# php-ci configuration build not working

Tags: php, php-ci

the configuration is not copying the build after a successful build
my configuration looks like this

```
build settings:
    clone_depth: 1
    ignore:
        - "vendor"
        - "tests"
        - "node_modules"
    mysql:
        host: "localhost"
        host: "root"
        host: ""
setup:
    composer:
        action: "install"
test:

complete:

success:
    copy_build:
        wipe: true
        directory: "var/www/project-name"
```

it would be nice if someone can give me an example of the configuration.
its my first time using php-ci

Comment: do you get any errors.

Comment: @Reinard its running now. but I noticed something.
when you don't change role:permission
TO
www-data:www-data on the server.
it won't read the new phpci.yml file on the project. but it will use the older phpci.yml.
what role:permission are you using?

and could you give an example how to use the Shell Command?

Comment: @Reinard
I changed the role:permission now I'm getting
E_WARNING: file_put_contents(/var/www/phpci/PHPCI/build/34_c8410.key): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Exception: Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/phpci/PHPCI/build/34_c8410.key): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/phpci/PHPCI/Model/Build/RemoteGitBuild.php line 153
E_WARNING: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
Finished processing builds.